# Very strange column string "single-quote-comment-brace-time-char"-bug substitutions in postgres selects - maybe related to JDBC only

Tags: string, postgresql, jdbc, comments, substitution

If you ever had something similar and ripped your hair out to find the problem - in short:

```
--'
select '{t'::text

 text
 -----
 TIME
```

???

Comment: Note: works as expected in psql, so this must be a JDBC glitch. BTW: the single-line comment formally is `-- ` (two hyphens and a space)

Comment: @joop: Thx for the test and hint. I almost always put the formally recommended space behind it for readability, but it does and will not change the parser any time, since the profit-cost-ratio is way too bad. I just wanted to write here some minimal syntax sample. In my original example I had something like `-- it won't foo bar bla` - which may be quite general english commenting :-/

Comment: It looks like the JDBC Escape parser implementation in PostgreSQL doesn't work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What a nasty bug and interesting how this could lead to really messed up data!**
It [seems to be known since 9.1](http://www.progtown.com/topic698152-postgresql-jdbc-function-braces-single-quote.html), may be related to the JDBC driver only and happened with our **9.3** as well!:

Here are some more details I found out (for helping to find and fix this ad hoc in your code or eventually by the "source hackers" ;) ) so far with example code below:

- a **single quote must appear somewhere in a single-line or multi-line comment above the select** (e.g. `--'`, `/*'*/`, `-- foo's cool`)
- explicitely given **strings must contain `{t` or `{d` to be substituted by `TIME` or `DATE`** respectively
- one of the **strings must be** explicitely (maybe also implicitely) of type **`text`**
- a closing brace in the same or another string somewhere is necessary to continue this substition (e.g. `select 'foo } bar'`)
- a closing brace in a comment disables the behaviour again (e.g. `--}`)

.

```
--'
select '{t'::text

union all select '{ta}'
union all select '{tfoo bar'

-- these are untouched
union all select '{ t}'
union all select 'foo { t}'

-- there seems to be an opening/closing "{" "}" match behaviour behind 
-- it since the 2nd row below
union all select '{t'
union all select '{ta}'
union all select '{tfoo bar'

-- also "d" seems to be a "trigger"
union all select '}{d}'

-- a closing brace in a comment seems to disable it completely again
union all select '{d'
union all select '{d'
-- }
union all select 'a}{d}'

 text
 ------------
 TIME 
 {ta
 TIME foo bar
 { t
 foo { t}
 TIME 
 {ta
 TIME foo bar
 DATE 
 DATE 
 {d
 a}{d}
```